# How to create two sequence out of one comparing one custom object with another in that sequence?

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

```
case class Submission(name: String, plannedDate: Option[LocalDate], revisedDate: Option[LocalDate])

val submission_1 = Submission("Åwesh Care", Some(2020-05-11), Some(2020-06-11))
val submission_2 = Submission("robin Dore", Some(2020-05-11), Some(2020-05-30))
val submission_3 = Submission("AIMS Hospital", Some(2020-01-24), Some(2020-07-30))

val submissions = Seq(submission_1, submission_2, submission_3)
```

Split the **submissions** so that the submission with the same plannedDate and/or revisedDate 
goes to *sameDateGroup* and others go to *remainder*.

```
val (sameDateGroup, remainder) = someFunction(submissions)
```

Example result as below:

*sameDateGroup* should have

```
Seq(Submission("Åwesh Care", Some(2020-05-11), Some(2020-06-11)),
    Submission("robin Dore", Some(2020-05-11), Some(2020-05-30)))
```

and *remainder* should have:

```
Seq(Submission("AIMS Hospital", Some(2020-01-24), Some(2020-07-30)))
```

Comment: I tried:
 `val (sameDateGroup, remainder) = submissions.partition { sub =>
      sub.submissionRevisedDate.equals(sub.submissionPlannedDate)
    }
` It gives me entire submissions in sameDateGroup list and empty in remainder.

Comment: What if `submissions` has 3 that match on a given date and 2 more that match on a different date? Should all 5 go to the `sameDateGroup` even though there are 2 different dates represented? And what about `None`? Should all the `None` values go in a `sameDateGroup`?

Comment: I have edited the question. same plannedDate and/or revisedDate goes to sameDateGroup and yes, all `None` values go in a sameDateGroup.

If plannedDate or revisedDate of submission_1  is same as in submission_2 or submission_2 goes to sameDateGroup

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question. What if 1st and 3rd share `05-13` and the 2nd and 4th share `05-19`? Do all 4 go in to `sameDateGroup` even though 1st and 2nd have no common dates?

Comment: Yes, all 4 go into sameDateGroup. If 5th and 6th has `05-20` and `05-21` respectively goes to `remainder `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understand the logic here, submission `A` shares a date with submission `B` (and both would go in the `sameDateGrooup`) IFF:

```
   subA.plannedDate == subB.plannedDate
OR subA.plannedDate == subB.revisedDate
OR subA.revisedDate == subB.plannedDate
OR subA.revisedDate == subB.revisedDate
```

Likewise, and conversely, submission `C` belongs in the `remainder` category IFF:

```
    subC.plannedDate // is unique among all planned dates
AND subC.plannedDate // does not exist among all revised dates
AND subC.revisedDate // is unique among all revised dates
AND subC.revisedDate // does not exist among all planned dates
```

Given all that, I think this does what you're describing.

```
import java.time.LocalDate

case class Submission(name        : String
                     ,plannedDate : Option[LocalDate]
                     ,revisedDate : Option[LocalDate])

val submission_1 = Submission("Åwesh Care"
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-05-11"))
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-06-11")))
val submission_2 = Submission("robin Dore"
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-05-11"))
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-05-30")))
val submission_3 = Submission("AIMS Hospital"
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-01-24"))
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-07-30")))

val submissions = Seq(submission_1, submission_2, submission_3)

val pDates = submissions.groupBy(_.plannedDate)
val rDates = submissions.groupBy(_.revisedDate)
val (sameDateGroup, remainder) = submissions.partition(sub =>
          pDates(sub.plannedDate).lengthIs > 1 ||
          rDates(sub.revisedDate).lengthIs > 1 ||
          pDates.keySet(sub.revisedDate) ||
          rDates.keySet(sub.plannedDate))
```

Comment: What if submission_4 has a unique `plannedDate` but `None` value in `revisedDate` or vice-versa ?

val submission_4 = Submission("AIMS Hospital"
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-03-24"))
                             ,None)

val submission_5 = Submission("AIMS Hospital"
                             ,None
                             ,Some(LocalDate.parse("2020-09-24")))

Comment: @nikus; You wrote (in the comments), "all `None` values go in a sameDateGroup." And that's what this solution does (sort of). This code considers all `None` dates to be the same. So if more than one submission has a `None` date then they all go in the `sameDateGroup` because all `None`s are the same. If only one submission has a `None` date then the status of the other, non-`None`, date will determine which group it goes in.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is to count the number of matching submissions for each submission in the list, and use that to partition the list:

```
def matching(s1: Submission, s2: Submission) =
  s1.plannedDate == s2.plannedDate || s1.revisedDate == s2.revisedDate

val (sameDateGroup, remainder) =
  submissions.partition { s1 =>
    submissions.count(s2 => matching(s1, s2)) > 1
  }
```

The `matching` function can contain whatever specific test is required.

This is `O(n^2)` so a more sophisticated algorithm would be needed for very long lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

I'm sorry, some variablenames are not very meaningful, because I used different case class hen trying this. For some reason I only thought about using `.groupBy` later. So I'm not really recommend using this, as it is a bit uncomprehensible and can be solved easier with groupby

```
case class Submission(name: String, plannedDate: Option[String], revisedDate: Option[String])

val l = 
  List(
    Submission("Åwesh Care", Some("2020-05-11"), Some("2020-06-11")),
    Submission("robin Dore", Some("2020-05-11"), Some("2020-05-30")),
    Submission("AIMS Hospital", Some("2020-01-24"), Some("2020-07-30")))

val t = l
  .map((_, 1))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[Option[String], (List[Submission], Int)])((acc, idnTuple) => idnTuple match {
    case (idn, count) => {
      acc
        .get(idn.plannedDate)
        .map { 
          case (mapIdn, mapCount) => acc + (idn.plannedDate -> (idn :: mapIdn, mapCount + count))
        }.getOrElse(acc + (idn.plannedDate -> (List(idn), count)))
    }})
  .values
  .partition(_._2 > 1)

val r = (t._1.map(_._1).flatten, t._2.map(_._1).flatten)

println(r)
```

It basically follows the map-reduce wordcount schema.

If someone sees this, and knows how to do the tuple deconstruction easier, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: this also only uses `plannedDate`. didn't read the comment about revised date at the time.